# Коммутатор не видит одно из подключений

Tags: сеть

Здравствуйте.

Коммутатор `D-Link`, дешевенький на 5 портов. Вчера просто перестал видеть, что подключено к 1ому порту, помогает либо перезагрузка коммутатора либо попытка посильнее воткнуть кабель в  разьем, что не всегда помогает, можно так минут 5 простоять и ничего не добиться. При этом светодиод показывающий состояние этого самого 1го порта может периодически мигать, будто бы там на мгновение что-то подключено, а затем отключено вновь.

Вопрос не сложный, есть ли смысл пытаться его починить или еще что-то если стоит он 300р?

Comment: а если в другой порт воткнуть то что на первом?!

Comment: Пробовал, ситуация изменилась, точнее стала более понятной. 1ый порт это кабель во внешнюю сеть, остальное внутренняя подсетка, так вот, лампочки горят нормально, но буквально по прошествии нескольких минут он перестает пропускать пакеты, в стате подключения счетчик исходящих пакетов растет, а вот входящих останавливается. Гугл хром пишет 21ю ошибку, смена сети и советует перезагрузить все сетевое оборудование, что и спасает, но опять на пару минут.

Comment: 1ый порт это кабель во внешнюю сеть - это сеть с отличающейся адресацией ? Если так то, коммутатор тут совсем не кстати.

Comment: Не, адреса все в рамках одной сети, 192.168.0.1 - и до 4го, внешняя сеть это роутер уже с 5ым адресом, через него в инет выходим. Если к роутеру напрямую, то все шикарно работает кстате, еще одно подтверждение тому, что коммутатор не исправен.

Comment: Честно, я б выкинул ))

Comment: BlackOverlord, надо бы всё же в технике разбираться! То, что у вас барахлило - это не коммутатор, а роутер!

Comment: Да ладно, DES-1005A/B2 роутер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего это проблема в Д-линке.Но попробуй:

1. Скажем Этот провод их 1го порта переключить скажем в 5й - изменится ли ситуация.
2. В первый порт воткни кабель от клюбого компа и запусти ping c параметром -t (непрерыный). пингуй либо комп подключеный к 1му порту либо любой другой (2й к примеру) с 1го. Наблюдай - если пинг осыпится то свич в мусорку.
3. Ну это вообще перво на перво надо сделать прозвони тестером кабель который подключен к внешнему порту, если звонить нечем, можно переобжать. Если 3 пунк неосуществим (нет тестера или возможности переобжать) а при подключении к другому порту ситуация аналогичная, то кабель виноват, вероятность 99%

Еще могу предположить, что свич не справляется с нагрузкой когда все клиенты рвутся во внешнюю сеть, буфер на порту переполняется и он просто вырубается.

Comment: Спасибо) Проверил с 1 клиентом, кабель во внешку цеплял по очереди на каждый порт, пинг как вы сказали осыпается, минуты через 2 в среднем. Однако, что странно, между двумя компами в пределах помещения пинг работал нормально в течении получаса, далее не счел необходимым их мучать.

Answer (score 1):

Все прочел. Вердикт - в топку железку. К сожалению, D-Link`и часто славятся косяками...
Возьмите что-то более приличное...

Comment: Спасибо) Так и думал)